# Apply effect to audio using NWaves

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, audio

I'm using the `NWaves` package to apply some effects to audios and make a simple voice changer.
Actually, when I apply some effects to the current signal, it will not change at all and still is the same as before .
here is my code :

```
        WaveFile waveFile;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("O:\\result.wav", FileMode.Open))
        {
            waveFile = new WaveFile(stream);
        }
        var dist = new DistortionEffect(DistortionMode.SoftClipping, 20, -12);
        dist.ApplyTo(waveFile.Signals[0], NWaves.Filters.Base.FilteringMethod.DifferenceEquation);
        waveFile.SaveTo(new FileStream("O:/demo.wav",FileMode.Create));
```

I also tried different effects but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :

```
WaveFile waveFile;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("O:\\result.wav", FileMode.Open))
        {
            waveFile = new WaveFile(stream);
        }
        var dist = new DistortionEffect(DistortionMode.SoftClipping, 25, -20);
        var outputsignal = dist.ApplyTo(waveFile.Signals[0], NWaves.Filters.Base.FilteringMethod.DifferenceEquation);
        waveFile.Signals[0] = outputsignal;
        waveFile.SaveTo(new FileStream("O:/demo.wav",FileMode.Create));
```